# complex integral of 1/(z+1) + 1/(z-1)

Tags: complex-analysis

The question is to find a closed curve so that $\int \frac{1}{z+1} + \frac{1}{z-1} = 2\pi i$, with neither $\int \frac{1}{z+1}$ nor $\int \frac{1}{z-1}$ be zero.

From what I understand, if the closed curve encloses $z = 1$, then $\int \frac{1}{z - 1} = 2\pi i$, otherwise $\int \frac{1}{z-1} = 0$, so I am not quite sure how to achieve the requirements above.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would image that you realized that both residues are the same so if you did something naive like a circular contour enclosing both, you'd get zero. But you cannot simply exclude one of them from the interior of the region bounded by the contour, you will get zero for that integral as you have seen. Thus both must be on the interior of the region. The way out of this is to remember that the winding number is just as important as the value of the residue itself. I will let you take it from here as this is a pretty decent layup as it is.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hints! Based on your hint my new idea is that finding a closed curve that travel around z = -1 twice and around z = 1 once and with different orientation. Is this reasonable?